# Auto-filling rows in 'Rearrange Bands' Batch Processsing

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff

I am batch processing my raster files and trying to auto-fill the converted column as it is shown in the following screenshot:
[image]
I have 1100 image files and I would like my each output (converted) row to match its own input name. Fill down makes it easy to populate the rows. However, it only gives one file's name to all of them.
How can I do this?